# Unexplained Runtime Error with RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, random-forest, grid-search

I've been running a RandomForestClassifier on a dataset I took from UCI repository, which was taken from a research paper. My accuracy is ~70% compared to the paper's 99% (they used Random Forrest with WEKA), so I want to hypertune parameters in my scikit learn RF to get the same result (I already optimized feature dimensions and scaled). I use the following code to attempt this (random_grid is simply some hard coded values for various parameters):

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
# Random search of parameters, using 2 fold cross validation, 
# search across 100 different combinations, and use all available cores
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf,  param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 100, cv = 2, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)
# Fit the random search model
rf_random.fit(x_train, x_test)
```

When I attempt to run this code though my python runs indefinitely (for at least 40 min before I killed it) without giving any results. I've tried reducing the `cv` and `n_iter` as much as possible but this still doesn't help. I've looked everywhere to see if there's a mistake in my code but can't find anything. I'm running Python 3.6 on Spyder 3.1.2, on a crappy laptop with 8Gb RAM and i5 processor. Thank you for any help!

Comment: So what's the runtime error?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the calculation never completes. The code simply runs forever without giving any output, and I have to hard stop the entire console.